# Trouble installing OpenCV for android

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv

I am trying to get the OpenCV library working with android. I imported this library project into eclipse and made a new android project (the one I will develop) and just. I set the build path to include the OpenCV project in eclipse. However, when I run my new project, it says

`[2014-10-13 19:41:57 - OpenCV Library - 2.4.10] Could not find OpenCV Library - 2.4.10.apk!`

From what I understand, my new project should automatically pull in the library project and install it. I am wondering if I am missing any steps (because it doesn't seem to be pulling in the project)? Does it have to be the same target sdk? I am quite sure I followed all of the OpenCV installation guide and have no compile errors in the projects. Also if I load up the sample projects by directly installing the apks they seem to work fine. I even tried it with the OpenCV Manager app already installed but that didn't work either. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the OpenCV library project as shown below, the problem will go.

```
Project -> Properties -> Android
```

and press `OK`.

[image]

Comment: I tried this now, but I am still getting the same issue. I also tried selecting the OpenCV library under the "Project References" tab on the left. Any other ideas for things to try?

Answer (score 0):

You should check "Library" build option in Eclipse for OpenCV android project.(Not your project)

Answer (score 0):

Clean your OpenCV library,build it again and check in OpenCv library->bin->opencv library -X.X.XX.jar 
if there is a file  (X==> VERSION)(see picture).
[See this for .jar file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U78Z.jpg).
 If this file does not exist then your library is not generated then check the video it might help [This should help if your library is not built](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qsgY3zcR4bU).

My personal experience:I wasn't able to generate the jar file for some reasons using OpenCv2.4.10 .If the same happens to you consider using OPENCVTEGRA library it works at least for me.

Answering 1st time. Hope this helps